# AST creation in Bison

Tags: c, bison, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create a scripting language using Bison and C and I'm wondering if I'm constructing the AST the right way.  Here's the tree I'm trying to create:

```
+ 
└─ Steps
    └─ Step 1
    └─ Step 2
    ...
    └─ Step n
```

If that's not clear, I want to have a node that contains n steps.  The grammar I have right now looks like this:

```
Steps:          { $$ = create_steps(); }    
    | Steps Step 
    ;

Step:
    IDENTIFIER  StepBody    { $$ = create_step($1); }
```

Where StepBody is parsed into a node like I expect it to be.  In my code, I'm creating a linked list for steps to go into in `create_steps();` but that doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

I think I should have a `create_steps(node *inner_node);` function that takes the output of all of the `Step` processing functions and adds them to an array, but I don't understand how I could achieve this.

Originally, I had `Steps` setup like this in Bison:

```
Steps:          
        | Steps Step { $$ = create_steps($Step); }  
        ;
```

but of course, that called `create_steps` every time a `Step` was found which is not what I'm going for.  Plus, I got a warning for "empty rule for typed nonterminal, and no action" which is probably not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the empty production (ε) in `Steps`:

```
Steps:  Step         { $$ = create_steps($1); }
        | Steps Step { $$ = create_steps($2); }  
        ;
```

.. and then the `Step` is appended to your growing tree. You can even pass on the growing tree this way:

```
Steps:  Step         { $$ = create_steps(NIL, $1); }
        | Steps Step { $$ = create_steps($1, $2); }  
        ;
```

This is so common in compiling (doing lists) that it occurs in most grammars.

Comment: This disallows a "Steps" input that has zero steps.  To allow that, keep the epsilon production and have it create an empty list.